# Design Considerations Using Springs `@Scheduled` and `@Async` Together

Tags: spring, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled, spring-async

I have some questions about using Spring's `@Scheduled` and `@Async` functionality together.

Lets say my requirement is to process 5 rows from a DB every 1 second, so in 1 pass of the scheduler thread would create 5 asynchronous threads
to process each row from a Database.

My questions are as follows:

1) Is there an alternative way to creating 5 ascynchonis threads instead of using a while loop within the scheduled method?

One problem I see with this approach is the thread pools active count may not equal the max pool size and therefore the loop will not break before 1 second has passed.

2) In some cases the log statement in the AsyncService i.e. `Executing dbItem on the following asyncExecutor : task-scheduler-1` displays  `task-scheduler-1` as the thread name and not `async_thread_` as i would always expect?

3) If my scheduler thread takes longer than 1 second to run, what happens the subsequent pass of the scheduler?

The asyncExecutor:

```
@Override
@Bean(name="asyncExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();        
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("async_thread_");
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);     
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

which is injected into a class with a scheduled method:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("asyncExecutor")
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Autowired
AsyncService asyncService;

@Autowired
private DaoService daoService;

@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "1000")
public void schedulerMetod() {

    try {       

        while (threadPoolTaskExecutor.getActiveCount() < threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize()) {
            DbItem dbItem = daoService.retrieveNewItemFromDB();         
            if (dbItem != null){            
                asyncService.processNewItem(dbItem);
            }
        }

    } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException ole){
        log.info(ole.getMessage());     
    } catch (Exception ex){
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }   
}


@Service
public class AsyncServiceImpl implements AsyncService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public void processNewItem(DbItem dbItem) {
        log.debug("Executing dbItem on the following asyncExecutor : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());     
        taskService.processNewItem(dbItem); 
    }

}
```

Comment: are you missing `threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize()`.

Comment: is it required?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but there was some use case like: if you configure it via @bean it's not required but if you configure it via an `AsyncConfigurer` it's required, or vice-versa. couldn't find the docs about it. sorry. just try to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: OK thanks, i can add it but it doesn't relate to my original questions.

Comment: I thought it might be related to the 2nd one.

Comment: Interesting! Will try it out - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` bean you will have twofold purpose as it implements both `TaskExecutor` (supports `@Async`) and `TaskScheduler` (supports `@Scheduled`) interfaces. You can configure like this:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("async_thread_");
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

If you give another executor name such as `taskScheduler1` then you should provide executor name as an attribute in `@Async("taskScheduler1")`.
By this implementation you already have answers for your questions 1 & 2.

About your 3rd question, if all threads in your thread pool are busy then your schedulers do nothing until a thread released then it executes the scheduling task. You may think to give the thread pool a bigger size.

Last but not least, only usage of `@Scheduled` is enough as it works asynchronously.